# NotificationListenerService not created

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin

Maybe stupid question, but I have already spent to many hours on this. 
I have my Kotlin listener:

```
package pl.bmideas.michal.bmnotifier

public class MyNotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {


    private var apiService :BackendApi? = null;

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.i("MyNotificationListener" , "Creating NotificationListenerService service")
        super.onCreate()
        (.........SOMETHING ELSE..............)
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.i(TAG, "DESTROING")
        (.........SOMETHING ELSE..............)
    }

    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        val sbnInfo = StatusBarNotificationExtended(sbn)
        Log.i(TAG, "REMOVED")
    }

    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        Log.i(TAG, "RECIVED`")
        (.........SOMETHING ELSE..............)
    }
    companion object {
       var TAG = "MyNotificationListener"
    }


}
```

and my config looks looks this:

```
<service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name="pl.bmideas.michal.bmnotifier.MyNotificationListener"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

I'm not doing anything special in Activity.

Yes - I've checked security option and my app has access to notifications.

Yes - I've tried pointing to service by dot instead of full package

In logcat I can only see:

```
12-23 12:56:54.989 889-889/? V/NotificationListeners: enabling notification listener for 0:  
ComponentInfo{pl.bmideas.michal.bmnotifier/pl.bmideas.michal.bmnotifier.MyNotificationListener}
```

I cant get instance unless i will bidn to this service in Activity wchich creates the service but still I get no info in logcat about notifications.

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

Holly.... 
after rewriting this code to pure Java it works..... but why?

Comment: Hi bro, can you share the code for JAVA, I've spent a lot of time trying to connect to the service but it doesn't work even with the permissions enabled for access to notifications. After accepting them the app closes, I have tried many examples and in all the same thing happens, API 28 for Android 9.0

Comment: Hi. it's a poor quality old code , but its there on github :https://github.com/bunny1985/Notifier/tree/master/app